# Angular 4 Material table highlight a row and change selected row color

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to change the color of a row when i select it in my mat-table. 
I already know it for the `background color` but I can not change my row color in `white` if I have selected it in my table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add your default class, say `class="table-row"`  and `tabindex="1"` to `<mat-row>` as

```
<mat-row class="table-row" tabindex="1" 
*matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
```

And, in css file write

```
.table-row:focus {
  background: tomato;
  outline: none;
}
.table-row:focus mat-cell {
  color: white; 
}
```

**[Stackblitz Demo highlighting table row on click with changed color](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-table-highlight-row-on-click?file=app%2Fissue-list%2Fissue-list.component.css)**

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this:

in html:

```
  <mat-row [ngClass]="{'selected': selectedRowIndex == row.id}">
    </mat-row>
```

in css:

```
.selected {
    color: white;
}
```